# Significance of characters used in lame's mp3 encoding histogram

Tags: windows, mp3, encoding, lame, vbr

When `lame.exe` is encoding a `.wav` file to an `.mp3` file in VBR mode, it maintains a character mode histogram showing the relative usage of the various bitrate packets.  Study of documentation [here](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/lame/svn/trunk/lame/USAGE) and [here](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php/LAME) shows that the `--nohist` switch can turn this display off, but makes no mention of the significance of part of the histogram being drawn with `%` characters and the rest being drawn with `*`.

So what are the two values that are being displayed in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What are the two values (`%`, `*`) that are being displayed in this manner?

> The `%` means L/R (stereo) frame, while the `*` denotes a M/S (mid-side stereo) frame. These only show up when using Joint Stereo.

Source: [Histogram characters in LAME?](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=869.0)

> As far as I know, the "*" are used for mid-side joint-stereo blocks, and the "%" for left-right stereo.
>
> According to the required bitrate and the phase difference, LAME choses for each MP3 block if mid-side stereo can be used (for narrow stereo) or if left-right stereo is required (for wide stereo / surround) to achieve an optimal relation between quality and bitrate.

Source: [% symbols in lame histogram [Archive] - Doom9's Forum](https://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-19499.html)